# How to query many-to-many based on some constraints in flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

If I have a `User` and `Item` model, and they have a many-to-many association with each other, how do I build a query that returns:

**(1)** All items that belong to any user named 'Bob'

I tried:

```
Item.query.filter(User.name == 'Bob')
```

Which returns all items regardless of the user's name (incorrect)

**(2)** All items that have the name 'shark' and belong to any user named 'Bob'

I tried:

```
Item.query.filter(User.name == 'Bob' & Item.name == 'shark')
```

Same as above, but only returns items named 'shark' regardless of the user's name. (incorrect)

My model definitions:

```
association_table = Table('items_users',
    Column('itemid', Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('userid', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Item(Model):
    # other fields...

    # many to many association
    users = relationship('User', secondary=association_table, lazy='dynamic', backref=backref('items', lazy='dynamic'))

class User(Model):
    # other fields...
```

What would be appropriate syntax for two queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join the tables you will query, so that filtering one will filter the combined row associated with the other.  Since you have defined a relationship between the two models, you can join on it rather than specifying a join condition manually.

```
Item.query.join(Item.users).filter(User.name == 'bob')
Item.query.join(Item.users).filter(User.name == 'bob', Item.name == 'shark')
```

Working with relationships and joins is covered in [the comprehensive tutorial in the SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins).