# querying from a many to many relationship sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, relationships

I have this database scheme, a many-to-many relationship:

```
Base = declarative_base()

association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('book_id', Integer, ForeignKey('book.book_id')),
    Column('author_id', Integer, ForeignKey('author.author_id')),
)

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    book_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(50), nullable = False)
    authors = relationship('Author', secondary = association_table, backref=backref('books', lazy= 'dynamic'))

class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'author'
    author_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable = False)
```

where I want to query data from. I know how to query from objects I created, like:

```
a=Author(name='Author One')
b=Book(title='Book Title One')
session.add(b)
session.add(a)
session.commit() 
a.books.append(b)
session.commit()
# repeat above steps with new variables a2 and b2
# a.books.append(b2) 
for i in a.books:
   print(i.title)
```

However, how do I query directly from the table to see what authors are related to a specific book? I.e., the next time I wan to use the database, but don't have the objects anymore. Things I tried:

```
for u in session.query(Book.title).\
        filter(Book.book_id==Author.author_id).\
        filter(Author.name=='Author One').\
        all():
    print(u) # doesn't seem to work, returns only one element.

x = session.query(Author).filter(Book.title.any(name='Book Title One')).all()
# gives AttributeError: Neither 'AnnotatedColumn' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'any' error.
```

But they all seem to fail, or return the incorrect amount.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699642/how-to-query-many-to-many-sqlalchemy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575502/how-to-query-many-to-many-based-on-some-constraints-in-flask-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can recreate your objects in a new session by querying the database.  For example, you can fetch an author

```
  author = session.query(Author).filter_by(name='Author One').one()
```

then just iterate over their books collection:

```
  print('Author\'s books:')
  for b in author.books:
      print(b.title)

Author's books:
Book One
Book Three
```

Or use the author object to query the Book model:

```
  query = session.query(Book).filter(Book.authors.contains(author))
  print('Books\' authors:')
  for b in query:
      print(b.title, ', '.join(a.name for a in b.authors))

Book's authors:
Book One Author One
Book Three Author Two, Author One
```

If you don't want to fetch the author object, you can query the Book model using the author's name like this:

```
  query = session.query(Book).filter(Book.authors.any(name='Author One'))
  print('Books by Author One:')
  for b in query:
      print(b.title, ', '.join(a.name for a in b.authors))

Books by Author One:
Book One Author One
Book Three Author Two, Author One
```